# Moq Returns method not working as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, azure-redis-cache

Take a look at this code:

```
var thirdLevelCacheMock = new Mock<IDatabase>();
RedisValue val = "not empty or null string";
thirdLevelCacheMock.Setup(m => m.StringGetAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CommandFlags>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(val));

CachingInfrastructure caching = new CachingInfrastructure();
caching._thirdLevelCache = thirdLevelCacheMock.Object;

var operation = caching.GetKeyAsync("bla", CacheLevel.Any);

Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => { operation.Wait(); });
Assert.IsNotNull(operation.Result);
```

As you can notice, i'm setting the return of `StringGetAsync` to a simple not empty/null string.

My problem is that, inside the `caching.GetKeyAsync`, the call to that method, is returning a null result. What am I doing wrong here?

Code for GetKeyAsync:

```
result = _thirdLevelCache.StringGetAsync(key, CommandFlags.None).ContinueWith((prev) =>
      {
            string res = null;
            if (!prev.Result.IsNull)
            {
               res = prev.Result.ToString();
            }
            return res as object;
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced `It.IsAny<string>()` by `It.IsAny<RedisKey>()`

Answer (score 3):

Try using async/await with Moq's `ResturnsAsync` to exercise the test instead of using the blocking call `.Wait()`.

```
public async Task TestMthod() {
    //Arrange
    var expected = "not empty or null string";
    var thirdLevelCacheMock = new Mock<IDatabase>();
    RedisValue val = expected;
    thirdLevelCacheMock
        .Setup(m => m.StringGetAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CommandFlags>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(val);

    var caching = new CachingInfrastructure();
    caching._thirdLevelCache = thirdLevelCacheMock.Object;

    //Act
    var actual = await caching.GetKeyAsync("bla", CacheLevel.Any);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: funny, if i change the `ReturnsAsync(val)` for `ThrowsAsync(new Exception())` i don't get an exception either...

Comment: I managed to get it working replacing the setup `It.IsAny<string>()`, for "It.IsAny<RedisKey>()"...